# Linq Entity Framework where parameter on joined table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am stuck trying to add a where parameter to my linq query on a joined table, I have a list of products displayed in ProductsListViewModel from the Products Table and need to filter by a FilterId parameter from the ProductFilters table, with SKU being the linked field, but cannot add the FilterId parameter to the where clause.

Here is a the code I have so far for the ViewModel:

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductFilter> ProductFilters { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public ViewResult List(string category, string filtermaterial = null, string filterlength = null, string filtername = null, string filterid = null, int page = 1)
{ 
    ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
    { 
        Products = repository.Products
        .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
        .Where(p => filtermaterial == null || p.FilterMaterial == filtermaterial)
        .Where(p => filterlength == null || p.FilterLength == filterlength)
        .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize),

        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = category == null ?
                repository.Products.Count() :
                repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
        },

        CurrentCategory = category
    };

    ViewBag.Category = category;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `Product` model:

```
public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the SKU for this product")]
    public string SKU { get; set; }

    public string MainImage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter product specification details")]
    public string Specification { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correct price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Product Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    //public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Product Group")]
    public string ProductGroup { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the search terms for this product")]
    public string SearchTerms { get; set; }

    public string FilterMaterial { get; set; }
    public string FilterLength { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Details1 { get; set; }
    public string Details2 { get; set; }
    public string Details3 { get; set; }
    public string Details4 { get; set; }
    public string Spec1 { get; set; }
    public string Spec2 { get; set; }
    public string Spec3 { get; set; }
    public string Spec4 { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<ProductFilter> ProductFilters { get; set; }
}
```

The `ProductFilter` model:

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    [Key]
    public int FilterId { get; set; }
    public string Filtername { get; set; }
    public string CategoryGroup { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
}
```

Modified controller with join

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, string filtermaterial = null, string filterlength = null, string filtername = null, string filterId = null, int page = 1)
    {         
        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        { 
            Products = repository.Products
            .Join(repository.ProductFilters, prod => prod.SKU, prodfilt => prodfilt.SKU, (prod, prodfilt) => new { Prod = prod, Prodfilt = prodfilt})
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Prod.Category == category)
            .Where(p => filtermaterial == null || p.Prod.FilterMaterial == filtermaterial)
            .Where(p => filterlength == null || p.Prod.FilterLength == filterlength)
            .Where(f => filterId == null || f.Prodfilt.FilterId == filterId)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Prod.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ?
                    repository.Products.Count() :
                    repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        ViewBag.Category = category;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: What does you current LINQ look like

Comment: Why does it look like you removed your ProductFiletrs form your Product class? With that in place, you could simply add
`.Where(p => p.ProductFilters.Any(pf => pf.FilterId == filterID))`

Comment: my mistake, I had commented out the last line of the product model earlier trying to fix a problem with plural naming. I have tried adding .Where(p => p.ProductFilters.Any(pf => pf.FilterId == filterID)) but get this error message The specified type member 'ProductFilters' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: you need join between product and productfilter..this will be more elegant and efficient.

Comment: I think I have created the join correctly and added the filter in but I now get an error 'cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebStore.Domain.Entities.Product>. I have added the modified controller code with the join to the main question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebStore.Domain.Entities.Product>`

Your Viewmodel expects a property of type `IEnumerable<Product>`. By joining Products with Productfilters, the returned entites are of type anonymous.

to solve this conflict you need to add a strongly typed select statement:

```
Products = repository.Products
        .Join(repository.ProductFilters, prod => prod.SKU, prodfilt => prodfilt.SKU, (prod, prodfilt) => new { Prod = prod, Prodfilt = prodfilt})
        // ...
        .Select( x => new Product { ... }) //add this and clarify the properties.
        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize)
```

OR you change your ViewModel

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductAndFilterVM> FilterProducts { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductFilter> ProductFilters { get; set; }
}
```

This would require you to create another ViewModel, which would represent the joined entity. But you still need the select.

Comment: I was just trying out some code along these lines, was getting confused by the Anonymous type, just tried adding .Select(p => p.Prod) which seemed to work and display the correct data, do you think this will be OK or should I declare all of the fields required within the new Product { ... }

Comment: No, if every property you need is avaiable I'd let it stand as it is. If you want to scrape off the last bit of excess data, define excatly what you need.